# docker-compose with container mongo ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mean-stack

I m new at docker so i tried to connect multiple container 
- mongo
- my app
- redis
and i get this error in chrome=> `code: "ECONNREFUSED", errno: "ECONNREFUSED", syscall: "connect", address: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080}`

here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "2"

services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
     -  all
  redis:
    image: "redis:3.2.1"
    networks:
     -  all
  node:
    image: "project"
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
     -  all
  backoffice:
    image: "back"
    links:
      - node
      - mongo
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - node
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    networks:
     -  all

networks:
  all:
    driver: bridge
```

my differents Dockerfile:

for mongo:

> FROM mongo:2.6
>
> COPY ./data ./
>
> EXPOSE 27017
>
> CMD ["mongod"]

for service node:

> FROM node:4.4.7
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY /api ./
>
> RUN npm install
>
> RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get install -y -qq \ git \ curl
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> CMD ["node","index.js"]

for service back:

> FROM node:4.4.7
>
> WORKDIR /api
>
> COPY . ./
>
> RUN npm install && npm install bower -g && npm install gulp -g
>
> RUN bower install --allow-root && gulp build
>
> RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get install -y -qq \ git \ curl
>
> EXPOSE 8181
>
> CMD ["node","index.js"]

can you please help me figure this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue, i was using version 2 of docker-compose but links are available only from version 3.
Just upgrade and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your port 8080 is already in use. Open your cmd and type netstat -a. This is for checking the ports availability.

Comment: the port is available and i still have the same error